# CSS Gradients with multiple angles

Tags: css, gradient

I need to create a gradient from left to right with three vertical colors and another gradient on an angle. Apologies for the poor image below. The black line would represent the angle gradient (if you could imagine it fading into black).
I have tried numerous ways, However, I seem to not be able to do this.
I would require this in CSS. Any help would be much appreciate, any further information required please ask.

[image: click here for image]

Thanks for your time.

Roddest.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/no963b18/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, you can adjust the values as you want:

```
background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 255), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 255)) no-repeat border-box, linear-gradient(to right, #0ff 10%, #f00 50%, #0ff 90%) no-repeat border-box;
```

There are two gradients, one black and transparent in the middle and from top right to bottom left, and a second from left to right, cyan, red and cyan.